# Add capacitor speech recognition to android mainactivity

Tags: android, reactjs, ionic-framework

I’m trying to use capacitor speech recognition, they said on android it need this code in order to be working on android

```
import com.getcapacitor.community.speechrecognition.SpeechRecognition;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initializes the Bridge
    this.init(
        savedInstanceState,
        new ArrayList<Class<? extends Plugin>>() {

          {
            // Additional plugins you've installed go here
            // Ex: add(TotallyAwesomePlugin.class);
            add(SpeechRecognition.class);
          }
        }
      );
  }
}
```

i’ve added it like this

```
package io.ionic.starter;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;
import com.getcapacitor.Plugin;
import com.getcapacitor.community.speechrecognition.SpeechRecognition;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Initializes the Bridge
        this.init(
                savedInstanceState,
                new ArrayList<Class<? extends Plugin>>() {

                    {
                        // Additional plugins you've installed go here
                        // Ex: add(TotallyAwesomePlugin.class);
                        add(SpeechRecognition.class);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

when i run build or emulate, it gives me an error like this

```
error: package com.getcapacitor.community.speechrecognition does not exist
import com.getcapacitor.community.speechrecognition.SpeechRecognition;
```

if i inspect hover to `speechrecognition` it says `Cannot resolve symbol 'community'`
anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but for a different capacitor-community plugin. I found [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/capacitor-community-firebase-analytics-not-working/199294) post in the Ionic forum which worked for me.

1. ionic build
2. npx cap sync android
3. (In Android Studio) Build --> Clean Project
4. (In Android Studio) File --> Sync Project with Gradle Files